# Number of paths using k coins

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

> Given a matrix where every cell has some number of coins. Count number of ways to reach bottom right from top left with exactly `k` coins. We can move to `(i+1, j)` and `(i, j+1)` from a cell `(i, j)`.
>
> Example:
>
> Input:  k = 12
>
> ```
>    mat[][] = { {1, 2, 3},
>                {4, 6, 5},
>                {3, 2, 1}
>              };
> ```
>
> Output:
>   2 There are two paths with 12 coins
>
> 1 -> 2 -> 6 -> 2 -> 1
>   1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 5 -> 1

I created a recursive definition for this:

> Let `Count(i, j, k)` be the number of ways to get from `M[0][0]` to `M[i][j]` using `k` coins.
>
> ```
> Count(i, j, k) = {
>    0:                                       if M[i][j] > k,
>    Count(i-1, j, k-1) + Count(i, j-1, k-1): if M[i][j] < k
> }
> ```

My reasoning for this definition is if the entry in the matrix (the number of coins) is greater than the number of coins we want (`k`), then we can't take that path, so the value in the table should be 0.

If the entry is less than or equal to the number of coins, then we can take that path by adding the number of paths from the top `(i-1,j)` and left `(i, j-1)`. I subtract `k` by 1 because the number of coins from the last entry was 1 less.

This is how I do it in the following dynamic programming function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

#define MAX_SIZE  10
#define MAX_COINS 20

int Count[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE][MAX_COINS]; // number of ways to get from M[0][0] to M[i][j] using k coins
std::vector<std::vector<int>> M;

int NumOfPaths(int C) {
    size_t N = M.size();
    // Number of paths to (0,0) with 1 coin is 1
    Count[0][0][1] = 1;
    // zero coins doesn't work
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) for (size_t j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        Count[i][j][0] = 0;

    // If the number of coins is greater than the max then Count[i][j][k] = 0;
    // Otherwise Count[i][j][k] = Count[i-1][j][k-1]+Count[i][j-1][k-1]

    for (size_t i = 1; i <= N; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 1; j <= N; ++j) {
            for (int k = 1; k <= C; ++k) {
                if (M[i-1][j-1] >  k) Count[i][j][k] = 0;
                if (M[i-1][j-1] <= k) Count[i][j][k] = Count[i-1][j][k-1] + Count[i][j-1][k-1];
            }
        }
    }
    return Count[N][N][C];
}

int main() {
    M = { {1, 2, 3},
          {4, 6, 5},
          {3, 2, 1}
        };

    cout << NumOfPaths(12);
}
```

When I apply the function to the example given in the problem statement, it returns 0, which is incorrect.

I'd like to know where my reasoning went wrong and how I can fix it.

Comment: Step through your code line by line, using the debugger and check all of the variables if they contain expected values.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I want to know if my reasoning is wrong, and if so why.

Comment: I can't tell if your reasoning is wrong (TL;DR didn't care), but your code obviously gives you the wrong results, such it's very likely. It's very rare the compiler goes wrong about something you didn't intend. So check your intentions first please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If you didn't read the question then your comment is obviously uninformed. What if I had the correct reasoning but a faulty implementation? I explain everything in the question.

Comment: Post a [MCVE] in 1st place please.

Comment: "If the entry is less than or equal to the number of coins, then we can take that path by adding the number of paths from the top (i-1,j) and left (i, j-1). I subtract k by 1 because the number of coins from the last entry was 1 less. "

1 less? Shouldn't it be "However many coins are at this square less"?

Comment: shouldn't `Count` pass on `k - M[i][j]` instead of `k - 1`

Comment: @vu1p3n0x That's probably right but when I replace it I still get 0.

Comment: One way to test your reasoning is to try with as simple inputs as possible, e.g. 2x2 matrix of 1s and 0s or 1s and 2s, that you can easily solve by hand and compare results. Or write a brute force solution that compares every path and then compare results for various test cases against your optimal algorithm version. In this case I'd also try running your algorithm with a different K, e.g. 11 or 13, in case you're off by one.

Comment: You need to fill in counts for the left edge and top edge: at the moment there's no way to reach 0,0. You're also using N as a vector index when that's too large, and testing M[i-1][j-1] against k when your algorithm was M[i][j].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems are

- you're initialising `Count[0][0][1] = 1` when it should be `Count[0][0][M[0][0]]` (although that's the same here)
- you're never filling in `Count[0][j]` or `Count[i][0]`, i.e. there's no complete path to 0,0 from any cell that you're looping over
- you're off-by-one with your upper indices; you want `< N` in the loop and to return N-1 as the vector is zero-indexed
- you're testing k against `M[i-1][j-1]` in your loop not `M[i][j]`
- you're subtracting one coin not `M[i][j]` coins (as Edward and vu1p3n0x point out in the comments)

Here's a fixed loop:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
  for (size_t j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
    if ((i == 0) && (j == 0)) {
      // Skip 0,0: we've populated that already
      continue;
    }
    for (int k = 1; k <= C; ++k) {
      if (M[i][j] >  k) Count[i][j][k] = 0;
      if (M[i][j] <= k) {
        int ways = 0;
        if (i >= 1) ways += Count[i - 1][j][k - M[i][j]];
        if (j >= 1) ways += Count[i][j - 1][k - M[i][j]];
        Count[i][j][k] = ways;
      }
    }
  }
}
return Count[N-1][N-1][C];
```

Alternatively, maybe I misunderstood: were you deliberately counting the top-left square as 1,1 so that you didn't need to check if we were in-bounds for you i-1 and j-1 check, since there'd always be a row of zeroes to spill into? That would make sense for the return [N][N] and the M[i-1][j-1] I suppose. In that case you'd want to

- initialise 1,1 not 0,0 as [1][1][1] = 1, and skip 1,1 in the loop as above
- subtract M[i-1][j-1] coins from k now, instead of 1
- increase MAX_COINS by one if you do need to cope with 10x10, since otherwise you can only accept 9x9

Comment: This is a very good answer, and yes you were right about me wanting to make sure I was in bounds - that's where most of the problems came from I see.

Comment: @templateboy _"and yes you were right about me wanting to make sure I was in bounds"_ That's what I actually expected you to figure out with the debugger when stepping through your code. Dude ....

Comment: @templateboy _"simply out of lethargy"_ Which one's _lethargy_ first? Yours denying to thoroughly debugging your crap yourself, or mine tired of answering questions _"debug my code for me plz"_?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Nobody's asking for anyone to debug. I was asking whether or not my logic about the problem was correct (I explained my methodology in the question itself) and if not what was wrong. Just stop being lazy and read the question.

Comment: @templateboy Just stop being lazy and debug our code in 1st place please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Which I did.